# Impala - Check if a string is a number

Tags: sql, impala

Is there any way to check if a string is a number in Impala?
like `is_numeric` is SQL?

Answer (score 4):

This did work for me:

```
select
  case
    when cast(mycol as double) is not null
    then 'numeric'
    else 'string'
  end
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

The '[regep_like](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_like)' function is helpful here. For instance, the following will select integers:

```
select * from table where regexp_like(field,'^[[:digit:]]+$')
```